# Struts2 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException (form value type)

Tags: jsp, struts2

This happens not all the time, but frequently, and it's annoying. When I try to get a value from <s:form /> other than String (declared in Action), it gives me an exception like java.lang.NoSuchMethodException.

> Nov 23, 2011 4:13:20 PM
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
> WARNING: Error setting expression 'passengers' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@157b2d'
> ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setPassengers" failed for object com.deveto.struts.actions.BookFlightAction@14928cc
> [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> com.deveto.struts.actions.BookFlightAction.setPassengers([Ljava.lang.String;)]

The code from Action:

```
private Integer passengers;

public Integer getPassengers() {
    return passengers;
}

public void setPassengers(Integer passengers) {
    this.passengers = passengers;
}
```

The jsp:

```
<s:form action="book-flight" theme="simple">
        <s:textfield name="passengers" value=""/>
</s:form>
```

And it is strange that it happens at random all the time, not at some specific point. Do you guys have some advices?

**Update: I found this:**

**1) https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6434149**

**2) http://dev.bostone.us/2009/02/23/javaxfacesfacesexception-javalangclassnotfoundexception-ljavalangstring/#awp::2009/02/23/javaxfacesfacesexception-javalangclassnotfoundexception-ljavalangstring/ (but it is for Eclipse only)**

Comment: shouldn't the value be an integer like `value=0` because `""` should be a `String` and you only have `setPassanders(Integer)` and not `setPassanders(String)`. Also you probably have to set the `type` somewhere

Comment: This is a trick for autocomplete-off, but when I submit the form, there is a value, entered by the user.

Comment: Give an example of the value that throws the exception. Your method is expecting an Integer, make sure it is one and not a String instead.

Comment: It is an Integer, I am 200% convinced, an it is 7 for example.

Comment: I'n not sure, but it may need an `int` field instead of Integer.

Comment: It's the same result, even with Double or double and Float or float.

Comment: Do you have any other code inside your jsp?? other than this property files like any ajax call etc??

Comment: AJAX nope, but jQuery, yes :)

Comment: i have a doubt on that actually :) have you put devMode =true ?

Comment: Yes, I put, and it goes to the "input" result, Without any errors. The exception is shown only in NetBeans.

Comment: if it going to input means interceptor is failing and which sending it back to input.It will only happen when input is not valid instance of primitive or type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case can only happen when incoming string values does not represent a valid instance of primitive or types.

since as per your statement it is happening only few time which indicates that the input is not what expected

OGNL provides out of the box type conversion for all of primitive and its wrapper types.
Just debug this to find out what exactly is being passed in passengers.

```
 There is no need to do any type conversion in struts2 until unless it is 
 being not provided by OGNL else you are not using 
 framework build in capabilities
```

Comment: Can you post your struts config file and jsp some what all data inside form field?? Just eager what can be an issue as i never faced it.

Comment: Look in the first post, I updated it. Now I need somehow to fix it. :)

Comment: @DenisHoss: i can't see struts config file

Comment: There is no config file, because the problem is not in config file, there is 2 links, that redirects you to a bugs page

Comment: I already gone through them.your log is being thrown by the OGNL and it indicates that some how it is trying to set value for the attributes whose setter method is not defined. that is not a exception but as per my understanding there is going some triggering of some action and struts2 trying to set "passengers" params and it is unable to find matching setter method.Can only be debugged more if u able to pin point what are those "few" cases when this is happening

Comment: No, I don't know when those moments are. This happens at random and not with all my projects.

Comment: there is nothing random,just few day back i was using stuts2-jquery plugin for filling my drop down using ajax call and was facing similar issue it turned out that jquery-ajax plugin was the culprit some how when it was giving Ajax call was also trying to set values which was not there.

Comment: I only use this jQuery validation http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/ . I tried even without it, and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Like the name `Textfield` suggests this element only deals with text. You can force it to accept nothing but numbers by using a validator as described here: [Field Validators](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/using-field-validators.html)

<strike>You will however still receive a `String` like `"7"` instead of an integer. You have to do the parsing manually by using `Integer.parseInt(String)`</strike>.

edited out the wrong part.

Comment: I understand, but it is not all the time, sometimes the value comes correct and without exceptions :)

Comment: Well, that's weird. Could you overload `setPassengers(String)` and print the String that gets transmitted and whether it has whitespaces at the beginning or end?

Comment: @PeterT *Everything* that comes from a browser is a string. Type conversion happens at the framework level, and is automatic in Struts 2. You do not need to "parse manually".